# What is the definition of governing equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology, fluid-statics

1. What is the exact definition of the [governing equation](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=governing+equation)?
2. What is its purpose?
3. What makes it different than other equations of physics?
4. Why they are necessary?

Comment: Perhaps some additional context would be helpful?  There are some votes to close for the reason that the question is unclear.